# Indent according to subsequent line

Tags: shell, sed, indentation

I need to modify the number of spaces in certain positions.
Example:

```
    FixString VarString1
   VarString2
FixString VarString3
  VarString4
```

should become

```
   FixString VarString1
   VarString2
  FixString VarString3
  VarString4
```

In my application, FixString is a known string (which can be hardcoded)
while VarString1, VarString2 are variable strings.
The important thing is, that the spaces before FixString is adjusted to the number of spaces before VarString. Thus, the number of spaces before FixString can become more or less.

I hope you can help me with this.
I could of course parse the file backwards remembering the indentation in the previous line and apply it if the line starts with " *FixString"....
But this seems to be overly complicated.

I have now implemented the idea of Etan.
It seems to work for the example. I will have to try it on my actual files...

```
IFS=''
MEMORY=""
while read -r line
do
  STRIPPED=$(echo $line|sed 's/^ *//g')
  if [ "${STRIPPED:0:9}" = "FixString"  ]
  then
#     echo $line
MEMORY=$line
  else
NUM=$(echo $line | sed 's/^\( *\).*$/\1/g')
if [ ! -z $MEMORY ]
then
  echo -n $NUM
  echo $MEMORY | sed 's/^ *//g'
fi
echo $line
MEMORY=""
  fi
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Not sure you can do this with `sed` but you should be able to do this with `awk` easily enough. Print anything not "FixString" or "VarString". Hold any "FixString" line until the next line iff "VarString" fix indent and print else print both lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
sed -r '/FixString/{N;s/^\s*(.*\n)(\s*)/\2\1\2/}' test.txt
```

i.e., search for *FixString* (`/FixString/`), append the next line into pattern space (`N`), catch the string after the first blanks (`(.*\n)`) up to the line break and catch the blanks after the line break (`(\s*)`). After that substitute this with the spaces from the beginning of the second line (`\2`) + the rest string of the first line including the line break (`\1`) + again the spaces (`\2`).

Comment: Back references can include back references so: `sed '/FixString/{N;s/^\s*\(.*\n\(\s*\)\)/\2\1/}' file` would also do the job.